# How to override font size in a document class which doesn't (apparently) allow it?

Tags: fontsize

How to override font size in a document class which doesn't (apparently) allow it? (sapthesis.cls)

It seems that it uses \small as the default font. How can I change it to \normalsize without breaking things?

Comment: As far as I can see, the class uses 11pt size which is far from small

Comment: as @egreg says but it uses `\small` in some of its special pages, so presumably you have an error in your code that is allowing the affect of those `\small` to leak out, but it is hard to debug code if you do not show it.

Comment: Try throwing \normalsize into the code a few places and see what happens.